# Link Data From One Table To Another Which Are Joined By An Intermediate Table

Tags: django, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I've had a lot of difficulty designing my db but have boiled my problem down to the core issue.

Students can enroll in Packages. Packages are groups of many Modules.

When a Student enrolls in a Package I need an Extra_Data table to be automatically generated for EACH Module in the Package, linked to the Student. This will hold data unique to one Module and one Student.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    package = models.ManyToManyField(Package, blank=True)

class Module(models.Model):
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Package(models.Model):
    individual_modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How I display Packages:

```
{% for package in user.student.module_packages.all %}
<table>
    <th>Module</th>
    <th>Task Type</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    #<th>Complete</th> not yet implemented
    #<th>User Files</th> not yet implemented
    #<th>Teachers Files</th> not yet implemented

    <h3 class="account-heading">{{ package.name }}</h2>
    
    {% for module in package.individual_modules.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ module.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ module.task_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ module.topic }}</td>
        #<td>{{ module.extra_data.module_complete }}</td> this is an example of 
        # how I would expect to be able to handle the extra_data tables contents, 
        # though its turning out to be a real challenge
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I have tried many things, including using a Django [through](http://The%20closest%20I%27ve%20got%20is%20using%20a%20Django%20through%20relationship%20between%20Student%20and%20Module%20and%20going%20%27through%27%20Extra_Data.%20This%20didn%27t%20work%20as%20it%20directly%20links%20Students%20with%20Modules.%20%20%22To%20the%20student%20or%20to%20the%20enrollment?%20%22%20-%20I%27ve%20tried%20creating%20a%20separate%20%27Enrollment%27%20table%20but%20it%20hasn%27t%20helped.) relationship between Student and Module, going 'through' Extra_Data. This didn't work as it directly links Students with Modules - when a Student is given a Package in Django Admin no Extra_Data tables are created for the Modules in the Package.

-- I think this is irrelevant to my main issue, but Students can also enroll in individual Modules --

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: That's tough to follow - but let me try: You are trying to automatically add ExtraModuleData for each Module a student has when they enroll in a ModulePackage? Then you want to include file uploads accessible to them?

Comment: Hello again :). This is actually holding me up from implementing the last thing you helped me with - ajax checkbox. Yes, what you said is correct. Every Student needs an ExtraDataModule for each of his Modules, both individual Modules and every Module contained in a Package. I originally included a link to my RDNM but removed it. Thanks again.

Comment: The ExtraDataModule would contain data specific to that Student/Module. Once I get that working I should be able to create another table with a one-to-many relationship with the ExtraDataModule table, this new table would hold files the Student has uploaded for that particular Module.

Answer (score 2):

How about, instead of saving the modules and packages under `Student` you save all the data for this relationship under `ExtraModuleData` or a better name `StudentModule`. This keeps the student's module history separate from the Student model.

So, like:

```py
# a lot of this is short-hand
class StudentModule(models.Model):
    student = ForeignKey(Student)
    module = ForeignKey(BaseModule)
    package = ForeignKey(Package, required=False)
    files = ManyToMany(StudentFile, related_name='uploads')
    completed = Boolean()
```

You can list out the individual modules and packages, then loop through them using `StudentModule`'s module and package fields to 'select' the active ones.

Within the Django Admin Student context, that means you'd only need to add an inline for `StudentModule`, with each row giving the select box for modules and packages. A `StudentModule` can have an empty `package` field if it's not under a package. Preventing the need to save student package data separately.

For the uploads and other many-to-many data, I'd recommend saving them as their own models like below. This would be easier to wrangle outside the admin, since you can just query by `student_module_id` or even `student_module__student__id` if you don't have module id. And within the admin you can add them via inlines.

```py
class StudentFile(models.Model):
    file = FileField()
    student_module = ForeignKey(StudentModule)
    ..other data
```

Just to add extra context, your HTML can then be (assuming you passed a `st_modules = StudentModule.objects.filter(student=user)` variable to context.)

```
{% for sm in st_modules %}
   {{ sm.module.id }}
   {{ sm.module.task }}
   {{ sm.module.topic }}
   {% if sm.package }} {{ sm.package.name }} {% endif %}
   {% for file in sm.uploads.all }} {{ file.name }} {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to group the modules by package, a useful tag Django templates have is [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). You can use this like so:

```
{% regroup st_modules by package as package_list %}
{% for package, modules in package_list %}
  {{ package.grouper }} # package name if you need it
  {% for m in modules %}
     {{ m.module.id }} # etc
  {% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like it could work. I will try implementing it now/tomorrow and let you know how I go. My only question is, if a Student enrolls in a Package I'd need to create each StudentModule individually (Packages contain 12 Modules). Would it be possible to enroll a Student in a Package and not have to individually create each StudentModule (you don't have to give me code or too much detail, what you've already given me is great, i just want to make sure i can do it). Thanks again :)

Comment: A package is merely a container for modules. The relationship is between module and student, with some extra data for the relationship. You can write one custom manager method on the Student's manager named `enroll_package` that accepts a package instance and then iterates the modules, creating a new relationship for each. If the extra data is different per module, this becomes cumbersome and you may want to refer to an instance method on the StudentModule that handles the extra data. If the extra data is data you don't search for / relate on, you may opt to use json/text storage.

Comment: @Brenden I didn't really look into the hows of the StudentModule creation but Melvyn above has a good solution. It basically comes down to: "if a student picks a package, on save, loop through the package's modules and create a StudentModule object". I don't know the constraints of your modules, but if you want to avoid someone signing up for the same module twice (as a single and part of a package) you can add a UniqueConstraint: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense. My only question is where do I call ```enroll_package```?

Comment: Call it when saving, look at my last comment again. You can add a custom function to the Package model and run in in the model's `save()`.